# Не работает await nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Имеются две функции:

```
exports.userCheck = async (user) => {
   try {
       dbUser = await exports.findByLogin(user.login);

       if (!checkPassword(dbUser, user.password))
           return false;
       else return dbUser;
   } catch (err) {
       console.log("ERRORDBG: " + err);
   }
}

exports.findByLogin = (login) => {
   console.log(login);
   sql.query(`SELECT * FROM users 
              WHERE login = '${login}'`, (error, result) => {
       if (error) console.log("Error: " + error.stack);
       console.log(result[0]);
       return result[0];
   });
}
```

Но, в консоли:

```
login
ERRORDBG: TypeError: Cannot read property 'password' of undefined
RowDataPacket {
  id: 99,
  login: 'login',
  password: 'password'
}
```

Из-за порядка вывода данных в консоль, очевидно, что происходящее в *sql.query* выполняется позже *checkPassword*. Требуется приостанивить выполнение функции *userCheck* до полного завершения *findByLogin*.

PS *sql = mysql.createConnection()*

node-module mysql

UPD

Попробовал так:

```
let dbUser = exports.findByLogin(user.login)
    .then(() => {
        console.log(dbUser);
        if (!checkPassword(dbUser, user.password))
            return false;
        else return dbUser;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Но выводится: *Promise { pending }*

Comment: Изменение всех функций со стрелочных на обычные не помогает.

Comment: `await exports.findByLogin` - это конечно хорошо, но где ключевое слово `async` для функции `exports.findByLogin = (login) => ...`? Да и вообще запрос выполняется синхронно, вам нужно применить промис.

Comment: @Doigrales Спасибо, сейчас попытаюсь.

Comment: @Doigrales Обновил вопрос + сделал findByLogin async

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оберните функцию запроса в БД в промис по такому принципу

```
 exports.userCheck = async (user) => {
   try {
       dbUser = await exports.findByLogin(user.login);

       if (!checkPassword(dbUser, user.password))
           return false;
       else return dbUser;
   } catch (err) {
       console.log("ERRORDBG: " + err);
   }
}

exports.findByLogin = (login) => {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   console.log(login);
   sql.query(`SELECT * FROM users 
              WHERE login = '${login}'`, (error, result) => {
       if (error) return reject(error);
       resolve(result);
   });
 }
}
```